# Binding unknown inputs to viewmodel

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

http://jsfiddle.net/GfxxY/2/

```
var ProductOptions = function(data){
    data = data || {};
    SKU = ko.observable(data.SKU || ''),
    SizeName = ko.observable(data.SizeName || ''),
    SizeLetter = ko.observable(data.SizeLetter || ''),    
    ColorName = ko.observable(data.ColorName || ''),      
    ColorSwatchImage = ko.observable(data.ColorSwatchImage || ''),
    ColorImage = ko.observable(data.ColorImage || '')
    return{
        SKU: SKU, 
        SizeName: SizeName, 
        SizeLetter: SizeLetter,
        ColorName: ColorName,
        ColorSwatchImage: ColorSwatchImage,
        ColorImage: ColorImage
    };
};
```

On my Product page, I have say, T-Shirt #4343. This tshirt has 2 colors and each color has different sizes.

Where I am stuck and what I'm trying to accomplish is I need to be able to select a tshirt color, let the customer input values for the size / quantities and then generate a quote on the fly and add that color / size /quantity info to a new array then let them alter / delete it.

So my end result is:

**Tshirt Options**

Red  --> Small, Medium, Large
Blue --> Medium, X-Large, 2xlarge

**Added Items**

```
Red  --> Small     -> 4     --$43.43
         Medium    -> 134   --$234.34
         Large     ->  343  --$8743.11


Blue  --> Small     -> 4     --$43.43
          X-Large   -> 134   --$234.34
          2-xLarge  ->  343  --$8743.11
```

I'm stuck on how to achieve this with Knockout. An help would be amazing.

Edit:
No idea how to mark as complete or what not but  Origineil gave me exactly what I wanted. Thanks man!

Comment: Which part are you stuck on? What have you tried?

Comment: I'm stuck on how to go about making the Quantity fields observable so I can change the values.

On my drive in, I was thinking, maybe I need to redo how I get the data from the server. Maybe I need to add my data to the ProductOptions  object differently. Instead of say, an item for every color / size, I add every color to ProductOptions  and an array inside of ProductOptions  with the Sizes available. If that makes sense.

Comment: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/GfxxY/6/). I placed the required elements to cover the observable `quantity` and show a dynamic summation quote, but did not implement the `addToQuote`. If it were me, I would make the data structure resemble your `Added Items` section : `{Products: {Red: {Small: {Quantity: ko.observable(), Cost: 5.40}} }}` and let that structure "drive" the interface.

Comment: Wow! I cannot believe that's all it took. The addToQuote function be no issue for me. But damn. I struggled forever on this and that's all it was.  Than you so much!

Comment: If you are interested in an alternate [implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/vqFU5/) along the lines of your thoughts on reorganizing the data structure, I have been messing around with it throughout the day.